# redirect multiple stdout commands to one file

Tags: bash, redirect, file-io, stdout

I am looking for a way to redirect all output to a file. I was surprised when

```
date && sensors -A -f | awk '{print $2}' &&  awk '{print $1;}' /proc/loadavg >> ~/bunny
```

only saved the last statements output to file bunny. is there something I can do to keep it neat? Like brackets or something?  Or Do I have to do?:

```
date >> ~/bunny && sensors -A -f | awk '{print $2}' >> ~/bunny  &&  awk '{print $1;}' /proc/loadavg >> ~/bunny
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `&&` you are combining separate commands, each of which can have its own redirections. If you want a redirection to apply to a series of commands you can group them with curly brackets.

```
{ date && sensors -A -f | awk '{print $2}' &&  awk '{print $1;}' /proc/loadavg; } >> ~/bunny
```

or

```
{
    date
    sensors -A -f | awk '{print $2}'
    awk '{print $1;}' /proc/loadavg
} >> ~/bunny
```

Comment: The adsence of that semicolon was trppin me out. Thanks for that!